# How to make the text hidden in hover

Tags: css, visibility, hidden, font-size

I am creating a menu that each item has a text and in hover an email replaces.  So I do not know how to remove the text in hover.

here is my code so far:

```css
#home {
    font: 30px 'LeagueGothicRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #f9f8cc;
}

#home:hover {
    background:url(style/images/icon/home.png) #FFF;
    background-size: 83px 56px;
}
```

Comment: Can you set up a simplified demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not remove the text with css, but you can make the text invisible, by setting its color to transparent, so your css would be:

```css
#home:hover {
   color: transparent;
   background:url(style/images/icon/home.png) #FFF; 
   background-size: 83px 56px; 
}
```

If you have layout problems with this solution, you could also wrap another `div` around the text, and then on :hover set the display of the div to `none`:

**CSS**

```css
#home:hover .yourDivClassThatContainsText {
   display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="home">
   <div class="yourDivClassThatContainsText">
      Text Text TExt
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

you may set color: to transparent on :hover

Comment: this should be a comment not A ANSWER

Comment: ?? thanks to welcome me here, and THIS IS A SOLUTION ANSWERING THE QUESTION

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for another and a much simpler approach, simply add this to your CSS hover container:

> font: 0/0 a;

More information about the font shorthand property here:
[Another CSS image replacement technique](http://nicolasgallagher.com/another-css-image-replacement-technique/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use opacity and this is how:


Html

```
 <div id="home">
   <div class="yourDivClassThatContainsText">
      Text Text TExt
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.yourDivClassThatContainsText{opacity:1;}
.yourDivClassThatContainsText:hover{opacity:0;}
```

To make it really nice add this .transition class to the same div where  yourDivClassThatContainsText is here is the transition class:

```
.transition{-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease; -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease; -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease; -o-transition: all 0.6s ease; transition: all 0.6s ease;}
```

Thanks hope I helped